# проблема с цепочками вызовов

Tags: java, рефакторинг

У меня есть класс, который содержит несколько других объектов в качестве полей:

```
public class TabManager {

private JTextField fieldForName = new JTextField();
private Task task;
//и т.д.
}
```

Далее, с этим классом у меня взаимодействуют другие классы, которым объект класса `TabManager` передается в качестве параметра в конструктор.

Например:

```
public class OKButtonBuilder extends MyButton implements ActionListener {

private TabManager manager;

public OKButtonBuilder(String s, TabManager manager) {
    super(s);
    this.manager = manager;
}
```

Далее, в классе `OkButtonBuilder`, у меня идет вот такое обращение:

```
manager.getFieldForName().setText("some text");
```

Будет лучше, если я сделаю метод setName в классе TabManager?

```
public void setName(String s) {
    fieldForName.setText(s);
}
```

И в классе `OkButtonBuilder` буду вызывать так:

```
manager.setName("some text");
```

Правильно я понимаю, что это поможет избавиться от цепочек вызовов?

Comment: Если твой TabManager в приложении рассматривается как неделимый компонент, то правильно, если же как фасад, то не совсем правильно.

Comment: @Темкатоже, скорее как неделимый компонент. А почему если как фасад, то неправильно? Фасад же как раз предоставляет простой интерфейс для сложной задачи. А разве setName() не проще, чем getFieldForName().setText()?

Comment: фасад нужен не для этого. Он выводит на поверхность самые востребованные методы (делегирует их через себя), но в большинстве случаев ещё даёт и прямой доступ к функциональным компонентам

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Правильно я понимаю что это поможет избавиться от цепочек вызовов?

Все зависит от вашей задачи. Если вы работаете с `Field` только, для установки в него текста, то целесообразнее создать метод setName(), если же вы меняете и другие параметры объекта, то достаточно ограничится методом `getFieldForName()`.